# Mouse stopped working after running <sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall>

Tags: drivers, 20.04, mouse

My ubuntu 20.04 system after I ran

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and restart. Before restart it was fine.

my mouse stopped working. When I restarted, in the login menu the cursor response and the mouse seems working fine. But after login the mouse is completely frozen. I tried disconnect and reconnecting. wired mouse, Bluetooth mouse, connecting in different USB port. nothing helped.

```
`xinput list`
```

does not show a mouse is connected. However, if I restart again, the mouse works fine in the login menu, but not working right after login. This is kind of the weirdest problem I ever faced.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you try disconnecting and reconnecting after login or before? Usually it solves the problem after login.